# Can I get the HTML source of an element with Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Rather an odd request, I'm sure, but given a Jquery selector, can I get the raw HTML of an item (and its children) so that I could, for example, put an escaped version of that HTML back on the page?

I'm happy doing the escaping, I've just no idea how to return the HTML from an object.

If there's a simple DOM-standard way of doing this too, I'm just as happy with that.

---

Edit to addresss the "Oh why didn't you just Google that": Google it. You'll get Jquery's `.html()` and that will give you the inner HTML of an object. For example, let'sa say you have:

```
<div id="pants">naughty bits</div>
```

`.html()` will only return `naughty bits`. while the output I'm looking for is `<div id="pants">naughty bits</div>`

Comment: I don't believe that simply googling this wouldn't have given you the solution...

Comment: You can't get the original source---but yes, using `html()` you can get the browser's DOM-rendered source as HTML.

Comment: Per Archer's answer, this isn't as simple as `.html()` which *is* what you get if you Google. I've included an example in my question to explain why it's not the answer and why I'm not a *complete* Hodor.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you have the ID then you can do it like this...

**jQuery**

```
$("#ID")[0].outerHTML;
```

**Pure Javascript**

```
document.getElementById("ID").outerHTML;
```

Using `.html()` will only get the inner html and not include the element you specify by ID.

**Update**

There is now also a jQuery method to get the outer HTML of an element...

```
$("#ID").outerHTML();
```

Comment: +1 for the outer/inner distinction ;)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, html() method of jquery return html data with all tags as an string:
Example:

**Html Source**

```
<div id="DivId">
    <p> This is html concept </p>
    <br/>
    <p> This is jquery concept. </p>
</div>
```

**Jquery Code**

```
var htmlString=$("#DivId").html();
```

**Return Result is:**
htmlString:

```
    <p> This is html concept </p>
    <br/>
    <p> This is jquery concept. </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes its possible use `html()`

```
var source=$('#ID').html()
```

Answer (score 0):

> given a Jquery selector, can I get the raw HTML of an item (and its children)

Get the value using the `.html()` method:

```
var htmlOutput = $('#myselector').html();
```

> ...so that I could, for example, put an escaped version of that HTML back on the page?

Use the`.text()` method to set the string as plain text:

```
$('#anotherselector').text(htmlOutput);
```

(ie jQuery will fully escape it for you; you don't need to do it manually)

Comment: As others have pointed out, `.html()` (and text) is only suitable for inner HTML. It won't include the element I'm talking about (which is what I want too).

Comment: @Oli `.text()` here is used as a setter, so it really has nothing to do with the distinction of `outer/innerHTML`.

Comment: @Oli - No worries; Archer has given you a good answer for that so I won't repeat what he's already said. I posted my answer mainly to demonstrate that you don't need any escaping with `.text()`; none of the other answers picked up on that, so I felt I should add something.